# lldb breakpoint OpenEars objective-C

Tags: ios, breakpoints

After implementing OpenEars into my project, I ran into a issue... A breakpoint in 'ViewController setSlt'

The breakpoint is on this line:

```
->  0x10bd5a374 <+20>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdx
```

The application acts like it is about to start, then it crashes and xCode shows me the breakpoint..

I implemented OpenEars and the OpenEars sample app code into my project.  Their is no errors in the code.

But when i try to run it, it runs into this breakpoint.